# Can't use nginx in a container as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i am tryng to use nginx as a reverse proxy towards an Axum server with no success

I have 3 containers, one with postgres, one with nginx, one with an axum server.
there are no problems between axum and postgres, and the 3 containers ping each others.
Nginx serves well static files, but when i try to serve a POST request from nginx to axum, it fails with this error:

```
2023/05/20 18:22:45 [error] 31#31: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/submit-form" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /submit-form HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5000", referrer: "http://localhost:5000/form.html"
172.18.0.1 - - [20/May/2023:18:22:45 +0000] "POST /submit-form HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost:5000/form.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

this request should pass the form data to axum which is listening on port 8000.
the strange thing is that this program works with if it's not dockerized, but it seems that the problem is in nginx.conf, thas is:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 5000; 
        # default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        #root /var/www/html;
        #root /app/html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            #index index.html;
            #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri /index.html /about.html /form.html /success.html @backend =404;
        }

        location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://rust-app:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

    }
    
}
```

it complaints it not found /usr/share/nginx/html/submit-form file or directory, in fact it isn't.

my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  rust-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:15.3-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "listen_addresses=*"]
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine-slim
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - rust-app

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```